# css - Dynamic height with static content

Tags: css, swiper.js

I have found a good solution for Swiper with the gallery and it works great but there is a problem with height on mobile devices:
[image]

I have tried to replace this `height: 500px` to any dynamic but every time it's hiding without status height. Is there any solution to make it scalable without media queries?
https://jsfiddle.net/vertisan/j8a46vcg/1/

Answer (score 0):

What about this  https://jsfiddle.net/q1vr473z/ if u want just give max height

```
html,body,.container{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
#slider {
  height: 80%;
  max-height:500px;
}
```

Comment: But on mobile, I have still this margins (top/bottom) like on the image

Answer (score 0):

[Change the background-size](https://jsfiddle.net/dunglnh/fzpq1kav/6/)

```css
.swiper-slide {
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: It's cutting image on sides but I want to be scaled like now

Comment: ok, let's try with calculateHeight:true, or  autoHeight: true, //enable auto height